# WPF drag and drop selected text out from a TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, drag-and-drop

I have two WFP TextBoxes in a window. I select a part of text in the first TextBox and drag & drop the selected text into the second TextBox. The selected text is automatically inserted into the second TextBox and deleted from the first TextBox.

When the text is dropped into the second TextBox it triggers OnDrop event. But I wonder if any event is also triggered in the FIRST TextBox that would inform me when the selected text in the first TextBox is going to be deleted due to dropping it into the second TextBox?

I would like to control the deletion of the selected text in the first TextBox when it has been successfully dropped into any other TextBox or any control in a window (without needing to know which was the actual target control. However, I need to know if the target control has accepted the dropped text, because if it would not accept it, the text should not be deleted from the first TextBox).

Comment: Not that I can see.  Snoop shows only QueryContinueDrag on first textbox until you drop and then no more events.

Comment: Check out this thread, looks helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/F0A7B932-1F32-494A-945D-5C5271F5D7B5